# Alternate plug in for jquery bootstrap

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery bootstrap if anybody help me what is alternate for plug in for jquery bootstrap?

Thanks

Comment: hi blender, Need plugin like jquery bootstrap.

Comment: http://cowbelljs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [99Lime](http://www.99lime.com/), this is also a jquery based UI framework